compare three numbers
\fp_compare:nTF can be used in this case. Is there any better way to do this ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmm}{%
   \fp_compare:nT  {#1<#2}  {$#1<#2$}
   \fp_compare:nT  {#2<#1<#3}  {$#2<#1<#3$}
   \fp_compare:nT  {#1>#3}  {$#1>#3$}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\test{0.03}{0.1}{1} 

\test{0.5}{0.1}{1}  

\test{1.6}{0.1}{1}  

\end{document}


since the cases aren't mutually exclusive you can't do it that way. but you could avoid applying all of the tests every time. if you do test 2 first with TF, you can run tests 1 and 3 only if 2 is false, for example. depends whether you want to save typing or computation. not sure what you mean by 'better'.

save computation ,  avoid applying all of the tests every time.

so why do you run 2 if 1 is false? or 3 if 2 is false?

Do you intend to print nothing if all three are equal

yes. it's better to consider equal . but it would make the problem more complex.

It's impossible to answer if you don't precisely specify the terms of the problem.

@egreg  compare an unknown number with two known numbers.

@xcn You have three tests that are mutually exclusive. In a more simple case, if you test whether A < B, then of course if false you get A ≥ B without further testing. But since you seem to want to exclude A = B, you need to test two times. In your case, the same applies but with A, B and C, so you need to test three times if you want to exclude equality. Thus, there is no way to do this test with less than three ifs (whatever form they may have). At least this is as far as my mathematical understanding of this problem goes.

@JasperHabicht thank you for illumination.

I suspect there's a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do, but just taking the question on its own terms, you can use TF to avoid running all tests each time. How best to arrange them to minimise computation depends on whether some are more likely to pass than others.
E.g.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmm}{%
  \fp_compare:nTF  {#1<#2}
  {
    $#1<#2$
    \fp_compare:nT  {#1>#3}  {$#1>#3$}
  }{
    \fp_compare:nT  {#2<#1<#3}  {$#2<#1<#3$}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\test{0.03}{0.1}{1}

\test{0.5}{0.1}{1}

\test{1.6}{0.1}{1}

\test{0.3}{0.4}{0.1}

\end{document}

produces the same (odd) output as with the original definition. but you obviously need to take care of spacing.

what do you mean space ? I did thought nested \fp_compare:nT , but it seems not concise.

@xcn Why do you think that this is not concise?

@JasperHabicht was that question addressed to me?

@xcn hence my question about minimising typing or computation. regarding the space, did you compile it with the fourth case?

@JasperHabicht \fp_compare:nT is typed many times
